# How to show thumbnail of a pdf in a list of pdf files without any lag in my app?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-glide

I need to show thumbnail of each pdf file in a recyclerview of pdf files in my app. But, when I set it using Glide, the UI becomes jaggy. How should I create the image of the first page of the PDF file? How should I store that file? Please help me out  I have no idea about it.

This is how the UI looks:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
    // binds the data to the ImageView in each cell
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        PidifyFile currentFile = files.get(position);


        // helper function that adds/removes an item to the list depending on the app's state

//        holder.pdfImg.setImageBitmap();
        holder.pdfName.setText(currentFile.getName());
        Date lModified = currentFile.getDateCreated();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm aa");
        holder.pdfDate.setText(sdf.format(lModified));
//        holder.pdfSize.setText(humanReadableByteCountSI(currentFile.length()));

        //using Glide for smooth loading of images in recycler view
//        Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
//                .asBitmap()
//                .load(pdfToBitmap(new File(currentFile.getFilePath()), holder))
//                .into(holder.pdfImg);
    }



    private Bitmap pdfToBitmap(File pdfFile, ViewHolder holder) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY));
            final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
            if (pageCount > 0) {
                PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(0);
                int width = page.getWidth();
                int height = page.getHeight();

                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy").format(new Date());
                String path = pdfFile.getAbsolutePath() + timeStamp + ".jpg";
                imgFile = new File(path);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imgFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                fos.close();
                page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                page.close();
                renderer.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error123", "Nahi ho paya");
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: `How should I create the image of the first page of the PDF file? How should I store that file? Should I cache it and store it in the user's internal storage? ` That is all up to you and are many questions. You should do that all in threads if you dont want to block the ui. Showing them in a recycle view is another story. One question please.

Comment: You are compressing an empty bitmap. Do it after the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you coupling business login with UI and also converting image from file in the main thread. According to clean architecture the conversion part to bitmap should be part of usecase. I'm assuming you're fetching the list locally from your device, so, I would suggest to do this with the following steps:

1. First fetch the list of files from the UseCase.
2. Create async mechanism to create bitmap from the File which will not block the main thread.
3. Create a UI data class which can be live data and post your result in to the live data.
4. Pass the live data into the adapter as a list.

This might help you resolve the lag.

Also, as this is just a thumbnail, try to restrict the size of the image so that it will reduce calculation time and will improve recycler view performance.

This link also might help you.

[UI lags and is choppy when using Glide to load images in a RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002056/ui-lags-and-is-choppy-when-using-glide-to-load-images-in-a-recyclerview)

[Generate Thumbnail of Pdf in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38828396/generate-thumbnail-of-pdf-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of Glide for loading the images? I haven't tested it myself but could maybe work, something like this:

```
Picasso.get().load(new File(currentFile.getFilePath())).into(holder.pdfImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. It was not clean and proper approach more like a workaround, but it worked for me.

I was getting data from firebase through repository. And generating bitmap in my fragment and then setting in adapter using glide.

```
class EventsFragment : Fragment(){
    private lateinit var viewModel: EventsViewModel
    private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter
    private var _binding: FragmentEventsBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentEventsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[EventsViewModel::class.java]
        setupRecyclerView()

        // calling viewModel to get the data from repository
        viewModel.fetchLatestNews()
        //observing(latestEventLiveData is list of[link,type,bitmap])
        viewModel.latestEventsLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
            when (response) {
                is Response.Success -> {
                    response.data?.let { newsResponse ->
                        // calling to generate the bitmap
                        setBitMapUtilFunction(newsResponse)

                        // passing to adapter
                        myAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse)
                    }
                }
                is Response.Error -> {
                    //show error
                }
                is Response.Loading -> {

                }
            }
        })
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setBitMapUtilFunction(newsResponse: List<ExtendedNoticeModel>) {
        for (item in newsResponse) {
            val url = item.link
            // type is used to determine if pdf or image
            val type = item.type
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val bitmap = generateBitmap(requireContext(), url, type)
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        item.bitmap = bitmap
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private fun setupRecyclerView() {
        myAdapter = MyAdapter(requireContext())
        binding.rvEventsFragmentRecyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Here is the function to generate bitmap, Bitmap will be generated on the basis of pdf or image. Also it will only generate bitmap when file is downloaded.

```
fun generateBitmap(context: Context, url: String, type: String): Bitmap? {
    val bitmap: Bitmap?
    val directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val fileName = "your file name here"
    // bit map is generated on the basis of pdf or image
    if (type == "pdf") {
        val pdfFile = File(directory, fileName)
        bitmap = try {
            val fileDescriptor =
                ParcelFileDescriptor.open(pdfFile, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
            val pdfRenderer = android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor)
            val page = pdfRenderer.openPage(0)

            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(page.width, page.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            page.render(bitmap, null, null,
                android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY)

            page.close()
            pdfRenderer.close()
            fileDescriptor.close()
            bitmap
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e("PDF Thumbnail", "Error generating thumbnail", e)
            null
        }
    } else { 
        // for image
        val filePath = File(directory, fileName).path
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)
    }
    if (bitmap != null) {
        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 80, 80, false)
    }
    return bitmap
}
```

In last, adapter's onBindviewHolder

```
val currentNotice = noticesList[position]
val bitmap = currentNotice.bitmap

if (bitmap != null) {
    Glide.with(context).load(bitmap).into(holder.sivThumbnail)
}
```